# I want to read AGROVOC core rdf using protege, when i open the file in protege, it does not show any elements in the file

Tags: rdf, protege

Need to work with the downloaded version of AGROVOC rdf, but unable to parse it through protege, no error generated, file seems to be blank.

Comment: There is insufficient detail in your question for a meaningful answer. Where did you get the file from? Can you show (a sample of) the file contents? How exactly are you trying to import it in Protege?

Comment: unclear what doesn't work. It's also not clear which one you loaded, "core" or "LOD". And note, the whole taxonomy is SKOS-XL and not OWL. So what do you want to do with it in Protege? By the way, the latest version is always browsable in a public Skosmos instance: http://agrovoc.uniroma2.it/agrovoc/agrovoc/en/

Comment: I could load the "core" dataset, indeed it's mostly meaningless given that only a SKOS hierarchy is present. You need a SKOS hierarchy browser.